# Show the Following Operator is Well-Defined

Tags: logic, proof-verification

I have been tasked with proving the following claim. Just checking in to see if my logic is sound, as I haven't done Set Theory before. Cheers!

---

Let $x\Delta y$ be the set of $z$ such that either

- $z \in x$ and $z \notin y$; or
- $z \notin x$ and $z \in y$.

**Claim:** This operator is well-defined.

**Proof:** Let $\varphi(x, y, z) := \neg(z \in x \; \land z \in y)$. Note that $\varphi$ is a well-founded formula in the language of Set Theory $\mathcal{L}_\in$.

Now by the Axiom of Pairing, we know the set $\{x, y\}$ exists, and by the Axiom of Union, we know $\cup \{x, y\}$ also exists as the union of $x$ and $y$.

Finally, by the Axiom of Separation, we know $\{z \in \cup \{x, y\} \,|\, \varphi(x, y, z)\}$ exists because $\varphi \in WFF_{\mathcal{L}_\in}$.

Thus we have shown that for any $x, y$, there exists an output $x \Delta y$.

Now, suppose there exists another set that contains the elements of either $x$ or $y$, but not both. By the Axiom of Extensionality, this is the same set found above.

Thus we have shown that the output of $x \Delta y$ is unique, and therefore well-defined.

Comment: This is a really minor remark on language, but it is common to write "the set of **all** $z$ such that ..."

Comment: @DeeDuu It's also common to write it as it is in the question.

Comment: Looks good to me.